# No page break in framed

Tags: page-breaking, framed

I am trying to avoid framed boxes to break when they span on multiple pages (usually 2). Essentially they should get pushed down when the box is too long to fit on the page. This code for example breaks the second box at the end of the page and continues onto the next one, whereas it should be pushed down and start on the second page

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{framed}

\begin{document}
\begin{framed}
Text\\Text\\Text\\Text\\Text\\Text\\Text\\Text\\Text\\Text\\Text\\Text\\Text\\Text\\Text\\Text\\Text\\Text\\Text\\Text\\Text\\Text\\Text\\Text\\Text\\Text\\Text\\Text\\Text\\Text\\Text\\Text\\Text\\Text\\Text\\Text
\end{framed}
\begin{framed}
Text\\Text\\Text\\Text\\Text\\Text\\Text\\Text\\Text\\Text\\Text\\Text\\Text\\Text\\Text\\Text\\Text\\Text\\Text\\Text\\Text\\Text\\Text\\Text\\Text\\Text\\Text\\Text\\Text\\Text\\Text\\Text\\Text\\Text
\end{framed}
\end{document}
```

Unfortunately I cannot use the `\newpage` trick as the document is generated automatically from a set of definitions, which keep on changing. Thanks in advance

Comment: Give a look at `tcolorbox`

Comment: Just looked at some other options. `mdframed` solved it with the `nobreak=true` option. Thanks anyways